# How to use shell variables after doing sudo su

Tags: linux, shell

I am writing a script to fix a missing 'F' letter in a mail log file. The mail log file is continuously updating. I am getting a file name, after that I am doing 'sudo su' to get superuser access. Inside sudo, I am fixing a that missing 'F'. However, I am unable to use that file name inside sudo block. Please can anyone help me how I can export these shell variables inside sudo? I tried using export but its not working. the code block I have created is as follows-

```
    #Script to solve F issue
#----------------------------------------
#By Kapil Shirsath
#----------------------------------------

cd /var/spool/mail        #mail files reside in mail folder
echo "Entered in mail folder"

filename=`ls -lrt  99999*| sort -k 5 -rn | head -1 | tr -s " " "," | cut -d "," -f "8"`    # this will list the file with maximum size`

echo "File with maximum size is  $filename"
echo "----------------------------------------------------"
echo "Is it the file expected?(y/n)"
read choice
if test $choice == "n"
then
    echo "Exiting...."
    exit;
fi;

c=1
while [ $c -le 5 ]
do
    ls -lrt $filename
    echo $filename
    sleep 3
    c=`expr $c + 1`
done
echo "---------------------------------------------------"

sudo su<<'HERE'   #this will give you super user permissions
echo "Got root access"
echo "First line of the file is as below :"
head -1 $filename
echo "---------------------------------------"
firstline=`head -1 $filename`
echo "Repeat : $firstline"
echo $firstline | grep ^"rom" >/dev/null
if test $? -eq 0
then
ex -s $filename <<'EOF'
1s/^/F/
:wq
EOF
echo "F issue fixed!"
HERE


c=1
while [ $c -le 5 ]
do
    ls -lrt $filename
    sleep 3
    c=`expr $c + 1`
done
echo "---------------------------------------------------"  
else
    echo "Not finding the missing 'F' ! !! Kindly check with your system "
    exit;
fi;
```

Comment: Can't you just `sudo` run the entire script?

Comment: Yes I can Peehaa,but is there no other alternative?

Comment: You would need to unquote the `HEREDOC` marker and escape all the expansions you don't want happening and leave the expansion you do want happening unescaped.

Comment: Hi Estan,If you dont mind could you elaborate your answer giving sample code block?

Comment: Your easiest solution is to require the script to be run as `root`.  A simple test as the beginning like `test $EUID -eq 0` can tell you if it is being run as root. If not, just print a usage message and exit.